# Facebook API and access tokens

Tags: java, json, facebook-graph-api

Alright, So I make an Graph API Call and parse the JSON request.
Using a link like this I make a HttpGet request:
http://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?=access_token="MYACCESSTOKEN"

This works fine, but the problem arises maintaining the same access token throughout.

So I registered an app through facebook and made another httpget request to

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=_______&client_secret=_____&grant_type=client_credentials`

using the client id and secret provided. This returned an access token. But I can't use this access token at all does let me into 
http://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?=access_token="MYACCESSTOKEN"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second request returns an APP access token https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/

You need a user access token using one of the authentication flows https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/